# Noob seeking help with Database [Access]

Tags: database, ms-access, byte-order-mark

I'm fairly new at access and I have no clue how to handle this situation. I dont even know where to start so any help would be greatly appreciated.

So I have to design this data base that has items such as "audio board X.xx" When a customer orders lets say "audio board 2.4", the database will know that the board requires 2x4K Resisters and 4x2uf Capacitors and 2X4401 BJTs. And it would automatically pull them from the inventory when processing this order so later on I can just look at the inventory list lets say at the end of the week and will know what parts i would need to order to restock.

now, i looked for help online, the only thing i could find similar was something called "Bill of Materials" AKA "BOM" sheets or something... but none of them told me how to make one or anything like that.

I'm really new at this, and am a total noob. I'm using Access 2010. Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: How many different types of electronic components can be required by all of the possible items that a customer can order? I ask because the answer would help determine the best solution.

Comment: a customer can order lets say one board, and each board has 10 to 15 components that gets pulled out of the inventory.

Comment: BOM of is one of the most complex real-world entities to model in a database, but it seems to me to be what you're going to need. However, you may need only a subset of BOM functionality so could get by with a simplified structure -- it all depends on your particular requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, read http://r937.com/relational.html

You will need a design on the lines of:

**Parts**
ID -->Primary key
Description
Etc

**Components**
ID -->Primary key
Description
Etc

**PartsComponents** --> Junction table
PartID      ---)  ??
ComponentID ---)

If a part can have only one of each component, life is simple enough and PartID + ComponentID is your primary key, if a part can only have a set number of a particular component, it may be possible to treat the set as a single item, if the part can have a variable number of a component, things get a little more complicated. A quantity field in the junction table would probably work, though.

You then have a fairly standard set of tables for customers and orders, including an order detail table, which gets updated by an append query from the junction table information when a customer selects a part.

Comment: ya, no i did that and it works fine for 1 item. but lets say the customer orders 4 or the same boards. then i don't know what to do. because i need the query to run 4 times instead of once.

Comment: If the junction table holds a quantity, you can multiply it by order quantity in your update query.